# GWT: How to access in one stylesheet constants defined in another stylesheet from the same ClientBundle

Tags: css, gwt, cssresource

This problem is best described with an example.

I have the following ClientBundle in my GWT app:

```
interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
    public static final Resources INSTANCE = GWT.create(Resources.class);

    @Source("defines.css")
    Defines defines();

    @Source("appStyle.css")
    @CssResource.NotStrict
    Style style();

    interface Style extends CssResource {
        String appLogo();
        (...)
    }

    interface Defines extends CssResource {
        String formInputBackgroundColor();
        String formInputBorderColor();
        (...)
    }
}
```

The `appStyle.css` is the main stylesheet used by the application and the `defines.css` is a stylesheet containing only constants like:

```
@def formInputBackgroundColor #D8ECFD;
@def formInputBorderColor #7FAAFF;
(...)
```

Now I can use the constants in the `defines.css` stylesheet inside UIBinder templates and in application code without problems, but I can't use those constants in my `appStyle.css`.

I have already tried replacing `interface Style extends CssResource` with `interface Style extends Defines`, hoping that inheriting from the `Defines` stylesheet would give me access to the constants in the "child" `Style` stylesheet, but then the GWT compiler complains with errors like:

```
Rebinding my.project.client.resources.Resources
    Creating assignment for style()
        Replacing CSS class names
            The following obfuscated style classes were missing from the source CSS file:
                formInputBorderColor: Fix by adding .formInputBorderColor{}
                formInputBackgroundColor: Fix by adding .formInputBackgroundColor{}
                (...)
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it, but it's far from elegant and I would prefer another solution, like using some kind of inheritance or Annotations, if possible.

The way I got it to work is to `@eval` every constant I need from `defines.css` in the `appStyle.css` stylesheet, but that leads to a lot of code duplication and it's a mess to mantain.

```
@eval formInputBackgroundColor Resources.INSTANCE.defines().formInputBackgroundColor();
@eval formInputBorderColor Resources.INSTANCE.defines().formInputBorderColor();
```

If you have a better solution, please share.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing

```
@Source("appStyle.css")
```

with

```
@Source({"defines.css", "appStyle.css"})
```

should do the trick. By specifying both css files your `style()` will be a union of the two.